Need help to understand steps in an answer
Image
I do not understand how the author transform the expression underlined in blue to the expression underlined in red

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

They factor out $(k+1)^2$ using distributivity which is $xy + xz = x(y+z)$.

$\begin{align}
(k(k+1)/2)^2 + (k+1)^3 &= \left( \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} \right)^2 + (k+1)^3 \\
&= \dfrac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)^3 \\
&= \color{blue}{(k+1)^2} \cdot \dfrac{k^2}{4} \ + \ \color{blue}{(k+1)^2} \cdot (k+1) \\
&= \color{blue}{(k+1)^2} \left( \dfrac{k^2}{4} + (k+1) \right) \\
&= (k+1)^2 \left( (k^2/4) + (k+1) \right). \quad \blacksquare
\end{align}$

Please do not encourage junk questions by answering them, especially when the asker has shown no context or effort.
